# What funds do I need for a Schengen visa?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

My husband is a student in Munich. I wish to travel to germany and be with him for 3 months. What is the funds requirement for a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 1):

The funds requirement **for your subsistence in Germany** will be around €4000, but you will also have to convince the visa official that you are going to leave the Schengen area afterwards.

- The best way to do that is a stable, well-paid job. The pattern of income and expenditure matters, not just the amount of money when you make the application.
- Another way are solid ties to the local economy and society at your place of residence. That can mean relatives who do not travel with you, or owning property.
- Depending on his financial situation and residency status, your husband may be able to file a written bond with the municipal authorities where he promises to pay for any cost of overstay (unintentional or intentional). Such a *Verpflichungserklärung* is no guarantee of a visa, but it can help.
- Instead of a tourist visa for 90 days, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange about family reunification visa.